# Can we use Cropit with Angular 5?

Tags: angular5, cropit

Can I use Cropit plugin with Angular 5?
http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that Cropit plugin is only compatible with AngularJS and not with any version >=2 of Angular